# The sample DocuSign OAuth2 client (Java SpringBoot) web app is full of deprecated SpringSecurity classes, is DocuSign going to update these?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docusignapi

I used the [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) tool of DocuSign to generate a sample Java Spring-Boot project with authorization code grant flow, on exploring the code I am seeing a lot of classes that are deprecated by the Spring Security team.

For example, classes/interfaces used in `WebSecurityConfig` which is extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class, viz. `OAuth2ClientContext`, `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and more.

Is the DocuSign team going to update this tool for a more current version of the starter code soon? Furthermore, it would be really nice if a Readme file can be added explaining the sample project a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Raj for pointing it out. We're working on it. Hope to have an update soon.
You can also fork the repo https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-java and make the change and even submit a PR if you want to help (this is open source repo).

Comment: Thanks for replying Inbar. I would really love to contribute. 

However, for time being what would you recommend - using the current version of SDK (using pieces which anyway have to be migrated soon) or rather not using the SDK and writing custom code directly interacting with the underlying HTTP endpoints?

Comment: I would just do that for learning/investigating purposes. So that you know all the things you want to do with the DocuSign APIs, and make sure that you can do them. Later, you can update the code, all that changes is the authentication and the libraries. You don't have to use the code you download now, just "play" with it and throw it later.